# Dexguard / Proguard make app crash on Enum switch

Tags: android, enums, proguard, dexguard

After an update of Dexguard from 7.0.12 to 7.1.22, I'm encountering a crash on an Enum switch.

This only happens when Dexguard has run on our project (I suppose this is caused by a Proguard issue).

If I use hardcoded values, the crash does not occur.

Ofcourse, I want to avoid using hardcoded values.

## THE CRASH

The crash that occurs is the following

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lif;
```

This occurs on the line that states `switch(type) {` (see below)

## EXAMPLE

Some example code on which the app crashes (given that MyEnum is an Enum ofcourse):

```
MyEnum type = MyEnum.SomeValue;

switch (type) {
    case SomeValue:
        // Do something
        Log.i("Tag", "Hello world!");
        break;
}
```

Assume that the ordinal value of `MyEnum.SomeValue` is 1.

If I change `case SomeValue:` to `case 1:` it works like expected.

## WHAT I HAVE TRIED

I do not know why this crash occurs. I have tried to add these Proguard rules.

```
-keep enum * { *; }
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

But this does not fix the issue.

## UPDATE

I just checked the mapping file, all of my enum names etc are kept. Now I'm even more clueless of what's happening.

```
my.identifier.MyEnum -> my.identifier.MyEnum:
    my.identifier.MyEnum SomeValue -> SomeValue
    my.identifier.MyEnum[] $VALUES -> $VALUES
    6:6:my.identifier.MyEnum[] values() -> values
    6:6:my.identifier.MyEnum valueOf(java.lang.String) -> valueOf
    6:6:void <init>(java.lang.String,int) -> <init>
    6:7:void <clinit>() -> <clinit>
```

## UPDATE 2

Just took a look at the output. It's compiled to this.
Judging on the stack trace, I suppose `if` is not kept by Proguard.
Where is this defined? what do I need to add to make Proguard keep this?

```
switch(if.ˊ[var2.ordinal()]) {
    case 1:
        //some other code
        break;
```

## UPDATE 3

In the intermediates that line of code looks like this:

```
switch(null.$SwitchMap$my$identifier$MyEnum[type.ordinal()]) {
    case 1:
        //some other code
        break;
```

the fact that it states `null.$` bothers me. That does not seem right. or is that normal?

## UPDATE 4

Just reverted to our older version of Dexguard and removed the Proguard rules I added.

The crash does not occur anymore now, although the code still looks exactly the same. (The intermediates AND the fully compiled code)

## Update 5

Switched over to Dexguard 7.2 and it went flawless.

Comment: Can you contact support@guardsquare.com with this problem, including your configuration files and apk for further investigation?

Comment: I just came across the same issue when packaging up my app in Google's: 
Android App Bundle - AAB after downloading my app from Google Play.

The annoying part is: I didn't even enable ProGuard.

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement will create a synthetic inner class with an array field `$SwitchMap$MyEnum` mapping the ordinal of the enum field to an integer greater than 0. You need to make sure this class and it field are preserved as well.

Comment: How can I do or check this?

Comment: @SnyersK have a look at the created class files in your *build/intermediates/classes* folder. It should be an anonymous inner class. Then find out if proguard removed the class or the field. Also it would be interesting to know what exactly `Lif` is.

Comment: just updated my question with the code in the intermediates

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. When i decompile the class i see question marks (??? should be arg0 in this case)

```
public static cr a(String arg0)
  {
    switch (???)
    {
    case "caseOne": 
      ??? = a;
      break;
    case "caseTwo": 
      ??? = f;
      break;
    default: 
      ??? = null;
    }
    return (cr)???;
  }
```

if you reassign the argument internally like

```
arg0= arg0.toLowerCase();
```

then proguard understands what to put instead of the question marks

```
public static cr a(String paramString)
  {
    switch (paramString = paramString.toLowerCase())
    {
    case "caseOne": 
      paramString = a;
      break;
    case "caseTwo": 
      paramString = f;
```